# How would I convert this if-code to a for-loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering how I could possibly convert this holy nest of if and && checks, into a simple for-loop?
Any solutions are appreciated, since I'm completely lost and my brain has given up.

```cs
if (localModulebytes[i + 1] == convertedByteArray[1]
    && localModulebytes[i + 2] == convertedByteArray[2]
    && localModulebytes[i + 3] == convertedByteArray[3]
    && localModulebytes[i + 4] == convertedByteArray[4]
    && localModulebytes[i + 5] == convertedByteArray[5]
    && localModulebytes[i + 6] == convertedByteArray[6]
    && localModulebytes[i + 7] == convertedByteArray[7]
    && localModulebytes[i + 8] == convertedByteArray[8]
    && localModulebytes[i + 9] == convertedByteArray[9]
    )
{
    // Code
    similarities++;
}
```

I tried this code, which gave similaries that were way beyond the ones from my bee-nest to code:

```cs
for (var j = 1; j < 9; j++)
{
    if (localModulebytes[i + j] == convertedByteArray[j])
    {
        similarities++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you only want to increment similarities if all nine match?

Comment: Your upper bound on your for loop is wrong: `j < 9` is an exclusive bound and will stop at 8. You probably want `j <= 9`.

Comment: Yes, I only want to increment similaries if all nine match.

Comment: You know that arrays are 0 index based? so `convertedByteArray[0]` will be first entry in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you increase the similarities more times in the loop. You can try something like this

```
var sim = true;
for (var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    if (localModulebytes[i + j] != convertedByteArray[j]) {
        sim = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(sim) similarities++;
```

Comment: That's the right structure, yes, but you've copied the off by one in the loop range from the question.

Answer (score 0):

GreenChicken's answer is the way to do this with a for loop, but there's also LINQ:

```cs
if (Enumerable.Range(1,9).All(j => localModulebytes[i + j] == convertedByteArray[j])) {
    ++similarities;
}
```

Which isn't necessarily better, but I'll offer the alternative.

Comment: Absolutely an alternative. I’d probably shy away from it, but it’s a nice 2-line way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your initial code to a looped check, you could do something like:

```cs
var similar = true;
for ( var j = 1; j < 10; j++ )
    if ( localModulebytes[i + j] != convertedByteArray[j] )
    {
        similar = false;
        break;
    }
if (similar) similarities++;
```

But, considering you used the variable name `similarities` I suspected you wanted to count how many of those items were the same, not all of the 9. Your follow-up comment showed my assumption to be incorrect.